# Creating paper pinwheel from an image

Tags: modeling

I have to create a 3D model from an image.

For research purpose, the created model should be almost the same as what it looks like in the image.

My steps :

1. Create a simple triangle mesh
2. Add a simple deform modifier(Bend) to the mesh
3. Add a Bezier circle for this modifier
4. Adjust circle & modifier

[image]

[image]

No matter how I adjust the transform of Bezier circle or the deform angle in modifier, the model just don't look like the same as what it looks like in the image.

I have tried other ways such as curve modifier,
but this is the best result I could get.

Is there a better way of creating this model?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You may try to use ***Curve*** and ***Array*** modifiers starting with a simple *plane* instead of triangle.
[image]

Add a *curve* and a *plane*. Make sure they both have the origin points placed in the same position. Subdivide the *plane* many times with <kbd>W</kbd>-->*Subdivide* then give it a ***Curve*** modifier. Fit the *plane* to the *curve*.
[image]

Select diagonal vertices and connect them with <kbd>J</kbd>. Delete half vertices of the plane. One segment is ready!
[image]

Apply the *Curve* modifier and delete the *curve*. Snap the *plane's* origin point to the straight angled corner of a mesh as pictured below (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>). Next add an *Empty* there.
[image]

Apply the transformations of the objects (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>-->Rot&Scale). Add an ***Array*** modifier to the *plane*, change the *count* number as you like, uncheck the *Relative Offset* checkbox and check the *Object Offset* one. Type *Empty* in the window below. Select an *Empty* and rotate it as you like.
[image]

Comment: The result is perfect, learned a lot from this post.
Thanks!